# Application tried to present modally an active controller error

Tags: swift, xcode

I am trying to go from one view controller to another and then preserve the view controller state of the second view controller so whatever the user did on the second VC is saved when they return to it from the first VC. I have this code so far but I get this error "Application tried to present modally an active controller" when I try to return to the saved state of the second VC.

Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if detailViewController == nil {

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        detailViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailViewController") as? DetailViewController
    

    detailViewController?.items = items[indexPath.row]
    detailViewController?.images = images[indexPath.row]
    detailViewController?.notes = notes[indexPath.row]
    detailViewController?.text = text[indexPath.row]
    detailViewController?.listItemArray = listItemArray[indexPath.row]
    }
      self.present(detailViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your curly braces are confused, plus you are confusing *yourself* because evidently there is some other `detailViewController` instance property, which there should not be. Just instantiate, present, and let go:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    if let detailViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailViewController") as? DetailViewController {
        detailViewController.items = items[indexPath.row]
        // ... etc ...
        self.present(detailViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```